# Help with creating Recursive Algorithms

Tags: recursive-algorithms

Prove your algorithms correct.

- Write an (efficient) recursive algorithm Pow (a,n) than computes
  $ (a \in \mathbb R)(n \in \mathbb Z):n\geq 0, a^n $.
- Write a recursive algorithm that computes $a^{2^n}$.

This is what I have tried so far on the first one (not sure if its right):

```
pow(a, n)

{

    if n == 0

        return 1

    else

        return a*pow(a, n-1)

}
```

Comment: What have you tried? This question will end up closed if you do not show what you are stuck on.

Comment: just edited to show what I did

Comment: @user214870 You could try something like `return pow(a,n/2)*pow(a,n/2)` depending as n is even or odd.

Comment: I don't know what you mean? I need the algorithm for either pow(a,n) and a different algorithm for a^2^n

Comment: @user214870: exploit the fact that $a^{x+y} = (a^x)(a^y)$. As Arpan points out, you could try splitting $n$ into two parts and calculate for them.

Comment: How is this relevant to an algorithm?

Comment: @user214870 It takes down your time complexity from linear to logarithmic.

Comment: but i'm not looking for that I am looking for the algorithm that is needed to solve the discrete math problem

Comment: @user214870: what do you think the word "efficient" means in the question?

Comment: I don't know that's why i'm confused about the question

Comment: @user214870 There is nothing wrong with your algorithm except the line under else should be `return a*pow(a,n-1)`.

Answer (score 1):

To make it more efficient,
after the "n == 0" case,
insert this:

if n is even, return $(pow(a, n/2))^2$

This is correct because
$a^{2m} = (a^m)^2$.

This also makes the running time of order
$\log n$, instead of order $n$,
which is a good thing.

As is often the case,
nothing here is original.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested your algorithm?  It fails for pow$(2,2)$, returning $1$ instead of $4$. Arpan showed the fix. Then you have the problem of "efficient"  Your algorithm is $O(n)$  If you do [Exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) you can do better.  For the second, the naive thing is to use your pow function from the first.  As it didn't call for efficient separately, you could argue that is acceptable, but you can do better.

Comment: yea i fixed it. thanks